# google map not showing in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have developed an application in android which uses google map to display the list of shopping centers nearby to the location of the user.

This is my code to implement it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <org.fluturasymphony.recommendation.StoreMapView 
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="0aHtkSh4B8Ub3ELLFUMRWJD23wpEWJAsFxL-ilw"
        />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Code for store map activity.

```
public class StoreMapActivity extends MapActivity {
   List<GeoPoint> items = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();   
   StoreMapView mapView;  

  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);
    SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    String outlet_details = myPrefs.getString("outlet_details", "null");
    String show_all = myPrefs.getString("show_all","null");

    this.mapView = init();

    //MapController mc = mapView.getController();
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint(0,0);


       // String all_data = "[{\"outlet_latlng\":\"12.928569,77.58311\",\"outlet_id\":\"1\",\"outlet_desc\":\"BigBazaar\",\"outlet_loc\":\"Jayanagar4thBlock\",\"outlet_image\":\"bigbazaar.png\",\"recommended_products\":[{\"item_id\":\"3\",\"item_desc\":\"dettol\",\"item_image\":\"dettol.png\"}]},{\"outlet_latlng\":\"12.939235,77.578068\",\"outlet_id\":\"2\",\"outlet_desc\":\"FoodWorld\",\"outlet_loc\":\"Basavanagudi\",\"outlet_image\":\"foodworld.png\",\"recommended_products\":[{\"item_id\":\"3\",\"item_desc\":\"dettol\",\"item_image\":\"dettol.png\"},{\"item_id\":\"3\",\"item_desc\":\"colgate\",\"item_image\":\"colgate.png\"}]},{\"outlet_latlng\":\"12.958934,77.657161\",\"outlet_id\":\"5\",\"outlet_desc\":\"Total\",\"outlet_loc\":\"MurgeshPalaya\",\"outlet_image\":\"total.png\",\"recommended_products\":[{\"item_id\":\"3\",\"item_desc\":\"dettol\",\"item_image\":\"dettol.png\"},{\"item_id\":\"3\",\"item_desc\":\"colgate\",\"item_image\":\"colgate.png\"}]}]"; // temp data

                myPrefs = StoreMapActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                String client = myPrefs.getString("client", "godrej");
                String url = "http://10.0.2.2/Flutura/PHP/Core/Data/android.data.php?request=outlets";
                Log.v("url",url);
                AsyncHttpClient httpclient = new AsyncHttpClient();
                httpclient.get(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String response) {
                        try {
                            Log.v("response",response);
                            updateMap(response);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });                


}

  protected void updateMap(String json) throws JSONException{
     Log.v("json",json);
    ArrayList<String> outlets = Utils.ToArrayList(new JSONArray(json));

    Iterator<String> i = outlets.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()){
      String j = i.next();   
      displayOutlet(this.mapView,new JSONObject(j));
    }

 this.setMapBoundsToPois(this.mapView, items, 0.1, 0.2);
 mapView.invalidate();
  }


  @Override
  protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;// Minimum & maximum latitude so we can span it   
  }

  protected StoreMapView init(){

    // Initialize Map Object
    StoreMapView mapView = (StoreMapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);

    // Add zoom controls
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    // Add listener    
    mapView.setOnChangeListener(new MapViewChangeListener());

    return mapView;
  }

  protected GeoPoint displayOutlet(StoreMapView mapView,JSONObject outlet) throws JSONException{    

    String coordinates[] =outlet.getString("outlet_latlng").split(",");
    double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
    double lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]); 

    GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint(
        (int) (lat * 1E6), 
        (int) (lng * 1E6));

    this.items.add(p);

    List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);
    StoreOverlay itemizedoverlay = new StoreOverlay(drawable, this);


    ArrayList<String> recomm_products = Utils.ToArrayList(new JSONArray(outlet.getString("recommended_products")));
    Iterator<String> i = recomm_products.iterator();
    String recommended_products = "";
    int index = 0;
    while (i.hasNext()) {
       index++;
       String j = i.next();
       JSONObject item = new JSONObject(j);
       Log.v("j",j);
       itemizedoverlay.addItem(item.getString("item_name"));
    }
    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(p, outlet.getString("outlet_desc"), "Recommended Products");
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);

    mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);   

    return p;
  }

  private class MapViewChangeListener implements StoreMapView.OnChangeListener
  {

      @Override
      public void onChange(MapView view, GeoPoint newCenter, GeoPoint oldCenter, int newZoom, int oldZoom)
      {
          // Check values
          if ((!newCenter.equals(oldCenter)) && (newZoom != oldZoom))
          {
              // Map Zoom and Pan Detected
              // TODO: Add special action here
          }
          else if (!newCenter.equals(oldCenter))
          {
              // Map Pan Detected
              // TODO: Add special action here
          }
          else if (newZoom != oldZoom)
          {
              // Map Zoom Detected
              // TODO: Add special action here
          }
      }
  }

  public void setMapBoundsToPois(StoreMapView mapView,List<GeoPoint> items, double hpadding, double vpadding) {

    MapController mapController = mapView.getController();
    // If there is only on one result
    // directly animate to that location

    if (items.size() == 1) { // animate to the location
      mapController.animateTo(items.get(0));
    } else {
        // find the lat, lon span
        int minLatitude = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int maxLatitude = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int minLongitude = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int maxLongitude = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        // Find the boundaries of the item set
        for (GeoPoint item : items) {
            int lat = item.getLatitudeE6(); int lon = item.getLongitudeE6();

            maxLatitude = Math.max(lat, maxLatitude);
            minLatitude = Math.min(lat, minLatitude);
            maxLongitude = Math.max(lon, maxLongitude);
            minLongitude = Math.min(lon, minLongitude);
        }

        // leave some padding from corners
        // such as 0.1 for hpadding and 0.2 for vpadding
        maxLatitude = maxLatitude + (int)((maxLatitude-minLatitude)*hpadding);
        minLatitude = minLatitude - (int)((maxLatitude-minLatitude)*hpadding);

        maxLongitude = maxLongitude + (int)((maxLongitude-minLongitude)*vpadding);
        minLongitude = minLongitude - (int)((maxLongitude-minLongitude)*vpadding);

        // Calculate the lat, lon spans from the given pois and zoom
        mapController.zoomToSpan(Math.abs(maxLatitude - minLatitude), Math
.abs(maxLongitude - minLongitude));

        // Animate to the center of the cluster of points
        mapController.animateTo(new GeoPoint(
              (maxLatitude + minLatitude) / 2, (maxLongitude + minLongitude) / 2));
    }
} // end of the method
}
```

Code for Store Map View.

```
public class StoreMapView extends MapView
{ 
  // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // LISTENER DEFINITIONS
  // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

  // Change listener
  public interface OnChangeListener
  {
    public void onChange(MapView view, GeoPoint newCenter, GeoPoint oldCenter, int newZoom, int oldZoom);
  }

  // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // MEMBERS
  // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

  private StoreMapView mThis;
  private long mEventsTimeout = 250L;   // Set this variable to your preferred timeout
  private boolean mIsTouched = false;
  private GeoPoint mLastCenterPosition;
  private int mLastZoomLevel;
  //private Timer mChangeDelayTimer = new Timer();
  private StoreMapView.OnChangeListener mChangeListener = null;

  // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // RUNNABLES
  // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

  private Runnable mOnChangeTask = new Runnable()
  {
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
      if (mChangeListener != null) mChangeListener.onChange(mThis, getMapCenter(), mLastCenterPosition, getZoomLevel(), mLastZoomLevel);
      mLastCenterPosition = getMapCenter();
      mLastZoomLevel = getZoomLevel();      
    }
  };

  // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // CONSTRUCTORS
  // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

  public StoreMapView(Context context, String apiKey)
  {
    super(context, apiKey);
    init();
  }

  public StoreMapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
  {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
  }

  public StoreMapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
  {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
  }

  private void init()
  {
    mThis = this;
    mLastCenterPosition = this.getMapCenter();
    mLastZoomLevel = this.getZoomLevel();
  }

  // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // GETTERS / SETTERS
  // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

  public void setOnChangeListener(StoreMapView.OnChangeListener l)
  {
    mChangeListener = l;
  }

  // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // EVENT HANDLERS
  // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
  {   
    // Set touch internal
    mIsTouched = (ev.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_UP);

    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
  }

  @Override
  public void computeScroll()
  {
    super.computeScroll();

    // Check for change
    if (isSpanChange() || isZoomChange())
    {
      // If computeScroll called before timer counts down we should drop it and 
      // start counter over again
      resetMapChangeTimer();
    }
  }

  // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // TIMER RESETS
  // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

  private void resetMapChangeTimer()
  {
    StoreMapView.this.removeCallbacks(mOnChangeTask);
    StoreMapView.this.postDelayed(mOnChangeTask, mEventsTimeout);
  }

  // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // CHANGE FUNCTIONS
  // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

  private boolean isSpanChange()
  {
    return !mIsTouched && !getMapCenter().equals(mLastCenterPosition);
  }

  private boolean isZoomChange()
  {
    return (getZoomLevel() != mLastZoomLevel);
  }

}
```

But when i run the emulator i get a blank screen like this. How can I fix it?

[image]

Tell me what i am doing wrong here.

Hi i got a log cat error now.

01-03 07:28:02.585: E/MapActivity(3823): Couldn't get connection factory client

01-03 07:30:26.165: E/MapActivity(12298): Couldn't get connection factory client

My android manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.fluturasymphony.recommendation"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9"
              android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="org.achartengine.GraphicalActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".CategoryWiseSalesChartActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".ProductWiseSalesChartActivity" />
        <activity android:label="@string/home_screen" android:name=".HomeActivity" android:configChanges="orientation">            
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/store_screen" android:name=".StoreActivity" android:configChanges="orientation">            
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/store_list_screen" android:name=".StoreListActivity" android:configChanges="orientation">            
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/location_screen" android:name=".StoreMapActivity" android:configChanges="orientation">            
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/recommended_products_list_screen" android:name=".RecommendedProductsListActivity" android:configChanges="orientation">            
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/category_wise_sales_screen" android:name=".CategoryWiseSalesActivity" android:configChanges="orientation">            
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/product_wise_sales_screen" android:name=".ProductWiseSalesActivity" android:configChanges="orientation">            
        </activity>
                <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />


    </application>



</manifest>
```

Comment: is there any message on logcat?

Comment: no message in the logcat @hkutluay

Comment: are you testing in a google api emulator ?

Comment: yes i am testing in a google api emulator

Comment: can you give  a link to the package u are using ?

Comment: Hmmm i dont remember where i downloaded it.......its been too long

Comment: Did u set permission for INTERNET in manifest file???

Comment: yes i have set all the required permissions

Comment: Hi @Subburaj i have updated my manifest file.

Comment: Hi .. You have to export your apk and have to install in the emulator as well as mobile. Regarding Google maps it wont get displayed if you run from the eclips directly to mobile or emulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please Generate the new android map key then replace this key in XML...Might be issue is key is not generated properly...

Answer (score 2):

I think your android map api key not generate properly and then u just go on this link and get google map api key,
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/mapkey